SignalR prevent user from opening multiple sessions in different tabs
I am using simple hook to send messages to the client from the server(particular user thats logged in) I noticed that user is able to open url in different tab which should be perfectly possible, however I am not happy about the fact it counts as an extra connection to azure signalr(cost issue), I was trying to close the old connection once the user opens the url in different tab. I can easily identify the user, initially I was trying to store the connection inside a dictionary but I noticed a weird pattern where every odd-numbered new tab (e.g., 1st, 3rd, 5th) does not disconnect the previous connection, while every even-numbered tab (e.g., 2nd, 4th) does. I tried to use memory cache instead of dictionary but it is behaving exactly like before.
<script>
    const userIdentifier = '@objectIdClaim';//users unique id

    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(`/webhub?username=${userIdentifier}`, { accessTokenFactory: () => this.loginToken })
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace) 
        .build();

    // Handle server messages
    connection.on("SendMessageToUser", async (message) => {
        console.log("Received message from server:", message);
    });

    //handle opening new tab
    connection.on("ForceDisconnect", () => {
        connection.stop(); // Stop the SignalR connection
        showNotification("You have been disconnected, due to the new login");
    });

    // Stop connection when the user leaves the page
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", async () => {
        await connection.stop();
        console.log("SignalR web connection stopped.");
    });

    // Start the connection
    (async () => {
        try {
            await connection.start();
            console.log("SignalR connection established.");
        } catch (e) {
            console.error("SignalR connection error:", e.toString());
        }
    })();

    function showNotification(message) {
        //pops up modal
    }

</script>

My web hub c# code
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Something
{
    [Authorize]
    public class Webhub : Hub
    {
        // track user connections
        private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
        public Webhub(IMemoryCache cache)
        {
            _cache = cache;
        }
    
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var userId = Context.UserIdentifier;
            if (userId == null)
            {
                // No UserIdentifier available, disconnect this connection
                Context.Abort();
                return;
            }

            var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

            // Check if the user already has an active connection
            if (_cache.TryGetValue(userId, out string existingConnectionId))
            {
                if (existingConnectionId != connectionId) // New connection attempt
                {

                    Debug.WriteLine($"User {userId} connected BEFORE connection ID {existingConnectionId} connecting NOW {connectionId}");
                    // Notify and disconnect the old connection
                    await DisconnectOldConnection(existingConnectionId);
                }
            }

            _cache.Set(userId, connectionId, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));       

            Debug.WriteLine($"User {userId} connected with connection ID {connectionId}.");
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
        {
            var userId = Context.UserIdentifier;
            if (userId != null)
            {
                // Remove the user's connection when they disconnect
                _cache.Remove(userId);
                Debug.WriteLine($"User {userId} disconnected.");
            }

            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }

        private async Task DisconnectOldConnection(string connectionId)
        {
            // This will disconnect the client with the given connectionId
            // The client handles disconnection on the client-side
            await Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("ForceDisconnect");
        }
    }
}

here are the logs from this weird pattern
User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected with connection ID Ii9pOdJti4lRyA8QdG5zWAZq3viAr02.
User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected BEFORE connection ID Ii9pOdJti4lRyA8QdG5zWAZq3viAr02 connecting NOW fUpzQDu-Itg7yu-z4reQ_QZq3viAr02
User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected with connection ID fUpzQDu-Itg7yu-z4reQ_QZq3viAr02.
User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 disconnected.
User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected with connection ID R_qLkwKtxuE7nLE0TniVbQZq3viAr02.
User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected BEFORE connection ID R_qLkwKtxuE7nLE0TniVbQZq3viAr02 connecting NOW t3mNN20gUdhOK-UXIH5TQQZq3viAr02
User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected with connection ID t3mNN20gUdhOK-UXIH5TQQZq3viAr02.
User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 disconnected.
User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected with connection ID F9ne7QxXFTH1DZYs3lvVOQZq3viAr02.
User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected BEFORE connection ID F9ne7QxXFTH1DZYs3lvVOQZq3viAr02 connecting NOW 645t2jvOMbLgeJCVp6Gm5QZq3viAr02
User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected with connection ID 645t2jvOMbLgeJCVp6Gm5QZq3viAr02.
User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 disconnected.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated, what could be causing this or is there another way of doing that? Maybe storing that in the database? Also not sure how that Webhub class is instantiated this is the way I register it in Startup.cs so maybe some scope issue?
 services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(Configuration["SignalUrl"]);
   services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, MyCustomProvider>();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();

                endpoints.MapHub<Webhub>("/webhub");
            });


refer this link for bidirectional chatroom sample.

You really cannot stop that and I'm curious why you would. If your system cannot handle having the user in the same tab multiple times then you have a concurrency issue and should resolve it.

able to uniquely identify the user across browsers (this covers tabs, windows and browsers).You need to detect multiple sessions. A session could be another tab, another window or a different browser altogether. This would also include if the user used a different device altogether. For another tab there are 2 cases: they duplicated the existing tab or they opened in a new tab. In cases where a new tab/window/device was used you can have the client auto-generate some unique identifier.

The user closing a tab, window, device would need to disconnect the session but since none of that is reliable you'll be in a situation where a user may "close" a session but another session may still be active. This is going to cause false positives.

@Sampath "You really cannot stop that and I'm curious why you would". If some bot opens 50000 windows I will have to pay the bill, azure charges for each connection, how do you know I cannot stop that? Is that in documentation somewhere? I can detect multiple sessions as you can see in the code, my question is how do I close a previous one if there is one active already for that particular user I can identify in any other tab browser etc.

You're correct @Vladimir, Azure SignalR charges for each connection, and managing connections to prevent abuse (like bots opening many windows) is crucial. detecting multiple sessions per user is solid, and it's absolutely possible to close previous connections programmatically to mitigate costs.


how do I close a previous one if there is one active already for that particular user I can identify in any other tab browser etc.

Here you are sending a ForceDisconnect message to the previous connection, but it depends on the client responding to that message. This is not sufficient if the client is malicious or unresponsive.

Instead, you can forcibly terminate the connection on the server using SignalR’s Context.Abort().

public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    var userId = Context.UserIdentifier;
    if (userId == null)
    {
        Context.Abort();
        return;
    }

    var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

    // Lock cache access to avoid race conditions
    await _cacheLock.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        if (_cache.TryGetValue(userId, out string existingConnectionId))
        {
            if (existingConnectionId != connectionId) // New connection attempt
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"User {userId} connected BEFORE connection ID {existingConnectionId} connecting NOW {connectionId}");

                // Abort the old connection directly
                var hubContext = this.Context;
                await hubContext.Clients.Client(existingConnectionId).SendAsync("ForceDisconnect");
                Context.Abort(existingConnectionId); // Terminates the old connection
            }
        }

        // Update the cache with the new connection
        _cache.Set(userId, connectionId, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    }
    finally
    {
        _cacheLock.Release();
    }

    Debug.WriteLine($"User {userId} connected with connection ID {connectionId}.");
    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}



Context.Abort() immediately terminates the connection from the server side. It doesn’t rely on the client to disconnect voluntarily.

Implement rate limiting for new connections per user or per IP address. This can be enforced via middleware to protect against automated abuse.
services.AddInMemoryRateLimiting();
services.Configure<IpRateLimitOptions>(options =>
{
    options.GeneralRules = new List<RateLimitRule>
    {
        new RateLimitRule
        {
            Endpoint = "*",
            Limit = 10, // Max 10 connections
            Period = "1m"
        }
    };
});


For more information check the below logs:
[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:00:00 - User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected with connection ID Ii9pOdJti4lRyA8QdG5zWAZq3viAr02.
[DEBUG] 2024-11-28 10:00:00 - Connection established for user f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 with connection ID Ii9pOdJti4lRyA8QdG5zWAZq3viAr02.
[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:00:00 - User session added to cache: UserId=f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938, ConnectionId=Ii9pOdJti4lRyA8QdG5zWAZq3viAr02.

[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:01:00 - User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected BEFORE connection ID Ii9pOdJti4lRyA8QdG5zWAZq3viAr02 connecting NOW fUpzQDu-Itg7yu-z4reQ_QZq3viAr02.
[DEBUG] 2024-11-28 10:01:00 - Previous connection found for user f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938: Ii9pOdJti4lRyA8QdG5zWAZq3viAr02.
[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:01:00 - Sending ForceDisconnect message to connection ID Ii9pOdJti4lRyA8QdG5zWAZq3viAr02.
[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:01:01 - User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 disconnected with connection ID Ii9pOdJti4lRyA8QdG5zWAZq3viAr02.
[DEBUG] 2024-11-28 10:01:01 - User session removed from cache: UserId=f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938, ConnectionId=Ii9pOdJti4lRyA8QdG5zWAZq3viAr02.
[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:01:01 - User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected with connection ID fUpzQDu-Itg7yu-z4reQ_QZq3viAr02.
[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:01:01 - User session updated in cache: UserId=f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938, ConnectionId=fUpzQDu-Itg7yu-z4reQ_QZq3viAr02.

[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:02:00 - User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected BEFORE connection ID fUpzQDu-Itg7yu-z4reQ_QZq3viAr02 connecting NOW t3mNN20gUdhOK-UXIH5TQQZq3viAr02.
[DEBUG] 2024-11-28 10:02:00 - Previous connection found for user f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938: fUpzQDu-Itg7yu-z4reQ_QZq3viAr02.
[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:02:00 - Sending ForceDisconnect message to connection ID fUpzQDu-Itg7yu-z4reQ_QZq3viAr02.
[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:02:01 - User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 disconnected with connection ID fUpzQDu-Itg7yu-z4reQ_QZq3viAr02.
[DEBUG] 2024-11-28 10:02:01 - User session removed from cache: UserId=f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938, ConnectionId=fUpzQDu-Itg7yu-z4reQ_QZq3viAr02.
[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:02:01 - User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected with connection ID t3mNN20gUdhOK-UXIH5TQQZq3viAr02.
[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:02:01 - User session updated in cache: UserId=f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938, ConnectionId=t3mNN20gUdhOK-UXIH5TQQZq3viAr02.

[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:03:00 - User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected BEFORE connection ID t3mNN20gUdhOK-UXIH5TQQZq3viAr02 connecting NOW 645t2jvOMbLgeJCVp6Gm5QZq3viAr02.
[DEBUG] 2024-11-28 10:03:00 - Previous connection found for user f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938: t3mNN20gUdhOK-UXIH5TQQZq3viAr02.
[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:03:00 - Sending ForceDisconnect message to connection ID t3mNN20gUdhOK-UXIH5TQQZq3viAr02.
[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:03:01 - User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 disconnected with connection ID t3mNN20gUdhOK-UXIH5TQQZq3viAr02.
[DEBUG] 2024-11-28 10:03:01 - User session removed from cache: UserId=f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938, ConnectionId=t3mNN20gUdhOK-UXIH5TQQZq3viAr02.
[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:03:01 - User f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938 connected with connection ID 645t2jvOMbLgeJCVp6Gm5QZq3viAr02.
[INFO] 2024-11-28 10:03:01 - User session updated in cache: UserId=f1091f94-ae9b-42ad-a96c-3ed2ab309938, ConnectionId=645t2jvOMbLgeJCVp6Gm5QZq3viAr02.



you mentioned Context.Abort(). but in the example you are passing id of the connection     Context.Abort(existingConnectionId); which doesnt work because that method doesnt accept that can you give me correct example?
